# Test for empty macro definition

Tags: preprocessor, c-preprocessor

I've got a set of debug macros in tracing.hh. Whether it generates code and output is controlled by a macro flag in the real source code:

```
// File:  foo.cc
#define TRACING 0
#include "tracing.hh"
// Away we go . . .
TRACEF("debug message");
```

The flag TRACING should have a value; I usually toggle between 0 and 1.

Within tracing.h,

- `#ifdef TRACING` will tell me that tracing was defined.
- `#if TRACING` controls the definition of functional macros like `TRACEF()`

But what if TRACING has no value? Then `#if TRACING` produces an error:

```
In file included from foo.c:3:
tracing.hh:73:12: error: #if with no expression
```

How can I test if TRACING is defined but has no value?

Answer (score 32):

With Matti's suggestion and some more poking, I think the issue is this:  if `TRACING` has no value, we need a valid preprocessor expression in the test `#if ...`.  The [Gnu cpp manual](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/If.html#If)
says it has to evaluate to an integer expression, so we need an expression that is valid even if one of the arguments is missing.  What I finally hit on is:

```
#if (TRACING + 0)
#  . . .
```

- If `TRACING` has a numerical value (as in `#define TRACING 2 \n)`, cpp has a valid expression, and we haven't changed the value.
- If `TRACING` has no value (as in `#define TRACING \n`), the preprocessor evaluates `#if (+0)` to `false`

The only case this doesn't handle is

- If `TRACING` has a non-numerical value (*i.e.*, `ON`).  The cpp manual says "*Identifiers that are not macros . . . are all considered to be the number zero,*" which evaluates to `false`.    In this case, however, it would make more sense to consider this a `true` value.  The only ones that do the right thing are the boolean literals `true` and `false`.

Comment: You can still do a run-time test by making the macro a string using the `#` operator. C++11 may be able to turn that into a compile-time test (i suppose using `constexpr` could be a way) but not a preprocessor one.

Comment: also you have no means to distinguish between empty and `TRACING` equals 0

Comment: In Visual Studio 2017 `+0`is not a valid integer expression. I changed it to `#if (TRACING - 0)` and now it works like a charm.

Comment: This will go into the failing case when TRACING is set to 0. This is what the OP wanted, but still something to think about!

Answer (score 10):

Late to the party but I found a nice trick to distinguish

```
#define TRACING 0
```

from

```
#define TRACING
```

like this:

```
#if (0-TRACING-1)==1 && (TRACING-0)!=-2
#error "tracing empty"
#endif
```

If `TRACING` is empty, the expression evaluates to `0--1` => `1`.

If `TRACING` is 0, the expression evaluates to `0-0-1` => `-1`

I added an extra check in case `TRACING==-2` which would make the first test pass.

This doesn't work for string literals of course.

Comment: Perfect! Just what you need when the macro being empty is an error condition, but it being undefined isn't, or the opposite. Kind of a rare situation, but that's what I needed right now!

Answer (score 0):

Would

```
#if defined(TRACING) && !TRACING
```

do the trick?

Comment: Almost, I think.  See next answer:

Comment: This unfortunately won't work. You will encounter the same problem, where as TRACING will be removed. You will end up with something like: " #if defined(TRACING) && ! ". Thus, " error: operator '!' has no right operand " will raise at build time.