# Test if a C macro's value is empty

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I need to write some code to verify that a macro is defined but empty (not having any values). The test does not need to be in compile time.

I am attempting to write:

```
#if (funcprototype == "")
MY_WARN("funcprototype is empty");
#endif
```

the code does not compile, as `funcprototype` expands to empty.

Comment: The test does not need to be a compile-time test, but you want to use the result in a `#if` directive?  What if `funcprototype` has a non-empty replacement list but after replacement it expands to nothing (due to rescanning).

Comment: This seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4102351/test-for-empty-macro-definition

Answer (score 5):

If a run-time check is okay, then you can test the length of the stringized replacement:

```
#define REAL_STRINGIZE(x) #x
#define STRINGIZE(x) REAL_STRINGIZE(x)

if (STRINGIZE(funcprototype)[0] == '\0') {
    // funcprototype expanded to an empty replacement list
}
else {
    // funcprototype expanded to a non-empty replacement list
}
```

I don't think there is a general-case "is this macro replaced by an empty sequence of tokens" compile-time check.  That is a similar problem to "is it possible to compare two sequences of tokens for equality," which is impossible to do at compile-time.

Comment: it depends on what can be assumed about the token sequence. see e.g. [this silly macro](http://alfps.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/cppx-a-simple-unit-tests-framework/) of mine. **hark** (anticipiating obvious question) well it was made for a very special purpose

Comment: For this to work in Visual Studio, the `STRINGIZE(x)` needs to be defined as `#x` otherwise the substitution to `REAL_STRINGIZE` macro fails if `x` is an empty macro (will end up with a "not enough arguments" error). Is there a reason the macro is in two levels like this? I've seen it before but haven't read any good explanation as to why that is?

Comment: Nevermind, found my answer here: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan. Leaving it here for anyone who might find it useful.

Answer (score 2):

C++20 `__VA_OPT__` makes this easier:

```
#define EMPTY(...) (true __VA_OPT__(&& false))
```

Then:

```
if (EMPTY(MY_MACRO))
```

Answer (score 1):

With VS2013 the following works for me *at pre-compile-time*:

```
#define EXPAND(x) x
#define ARGS_dummy(...) dummy,##__VA_ARGS__
#define SELECT_from5(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,num,...) num
#define IS_EMPTY_impl(...) EXPAND(SELECT_from5(__VA_ARGS__,0,0,0,0,1))
#define IS_EMPTY(...) EXPAND(IS_EMPTY_impl(ARGS_dummy(__VA_ARGS__)))
```

`IS_EMPTY` expands to 1 if there is no argument or the 1st argument expands to nothing, otherwise to 0.
Additional arguments are ignored.

```
#define x2 X
#define x1
#undef x0
IS_EMPTY(); // () -> 1
IS_EMPTY( ); // ( ) -> 1
IS_EMPTY(,); // (,) -> 1 
IS_EMPTY(aaa,); // (aaa, ) -> 0
IS_EMPTY(,,); // (,,) -> -> 1
IS_EMPTY(x2); // (x2) -> (X)  -> 0
IS_EMPTY(x1); // (x1) -> () -> 1
IS_EMPTY(x0); // (x0) -> 0
```

Now you could generate a bit mask depending on empty/nonempty parameters:

```
#define check_5e(a,b,c,d,e) a ## b ## c## d ## e
#define check_5d(a,b,c,d,e) check_5e(a,b,c,d,e)
#define check_5c(e,a,b,c,d) check_5d(a,b,c,d,IS_EMPTY(e))
#define check_5b(d,e,a,b,c) check_5c(e,a,b,c,IS_EMPTY(d))
#define check_5a(c,d,e,a,b) check_5b(d,e,a,b,IS_EMPTY(c))
#define check_5(b,c,d,e,a) check_5a(c,d,e,a,IS_EMPTY(b))
#define CHECK_FIVE_ARGS(a,b,c,d,e) check_5(b,c,d,e,IS_EMPTY(a))
CHECK_FIVE_ARGS(aa, , x1, x2, x0); // -> (aa,,,X,x0) -> 01100
```

or you can choose sub macro depending on given arguments ...
(note that VERSION_BUILD is defined but empty!)

```
#define VERSION_Major 3
#define VERSION_Minor 22
#define VERSION_Patch 111
#define VERSION_Build
#define VERSION_Label debug

#define MAKE_VERSION_11(a,b,c,d,e) a##.##b##.##c
#define MAKE_VERSION_10(a,b,c,d,e) a##.##b##.##c##--##e
#define MAKE_VERSION_01(a,b,c,d,e) a##.##b##.##c##-##d
#define MAKE_VERSION_00(a,b,c,d,e) a##.##b##.##c##-##d##--##e
#define MAKE_VERSION_impl2(_de)  MAKE_VERSION_ ## _de
#define MAKE_VERSION_impl(_de) EXPAND(MAKE_VERSION_impl2(_de))
#define MAKE_VERSION(a,b,c,d,e)  \
   MAKE_VERSION_impl(IS_EMPTY(d)IS_EMPTY(e))(a,b,c,d,e)

// check 4th and 5th arg -> "MAKE_VERSION_10"
MAKE_VERSION_impl(IS_EMPTY(VERSION_Build)IS_EMPTY(VERSION_Label));
// -> 3.22.111--debug
MAKE_VERSION(VERSION_Major, VERSION_Minor, VERSION_Patch, VERSION_Build, VERSION_Label);

MAKE_VERSION(2, 3, 4, 5678, );     // -> 2.3.4-5678
MAKE_VERSION(2, 3, 4, 5678, beta); // -> 2.3.4-5678--beta
MAKE_VERSION(2, 3, 4,,);           // -> 2.3.4
MAKE_VERSION(2, 3, 4, ,beta);      // -> 2.3.4--beta
```